# Booting with kernel image size bigger than the RAM

Tags: linux, boot

Suppose I have a Linux server with 500 MB RAM and the compressed kernel image file of say 400 MB. After extracting it during booting, its size goes over 500 MB i.e. bigger than the RAM itself. What will happen in such a case? Will the server fail to boot? Will there be any specific message like OOM displayed on the console?

Secondly, suppose I add 5 GB swap space to the server? Will it boot in this case? I think swap gets initialized pretty late in the booting process and thus will not have any impact. Am I right here?

Answer (score 0):

There is SO MUCH ***"why would you care?"*** going on here, but I also get wanting to know what would happen for scientific purposes. ;^)

My answer is mostly *theory* as lord knows that I would never try this.

1. Your boot should fail if the uncompressed kernel doesn't fit into ram (for obvious reasons).  How would that work?.. *I guess* it *could be* designed to.. but it isn't.  You want the kernel to be lean and fast.. not worrying about weather it got loaded in full or not.  See  [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489787/does-the-bootloader-load-the-kernel-fully-into-memory)  for more info on that topic.
2. Kernel memory CAN NOT be swapped (again.. to me.. for obvious reasons).  See  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535379/do-kernel-pages-get-swapped-out)  for some discussion on that.

I mean.. if this was ***THE GOAL***.. the geniuses that work on the kernel could figure out a way.. but I for one am glad that they are working on real issues/advancements instead.

Comment: Thanks, it was a purely educational question and I too would never going to try this. I am going to accept this answer :)